# Future editor comments, a terrible idea?

Tags: discussion, editing, comments

Check the revision history (under "edited <date>") to see the question.

**EDIT:**

Between this line and the previous, there are many lines that are not rendered because SE think they are just HTML tags. Here is the content of them, whit the "<" and ">" stripped:

> HTML, or presumed HTML tags are stripped in the rendering, that means
>   I can add a comment like this. Is it a good idea to comment on
>   formatting, grammar or choice of words in this way to a future editor,
>   instead of in the comments, as it is not directly related to the topic
>   of the question?
>
> Of course just in the cases where the comment is of no use for a
>   person reading the question, except when that person want to edit it.
>
> example usage:
>   the following snippet is intentionally not marked as
>   code (Inside, to be hidden for everyone, except an editor.
>   /end example
>
> feature or just a terrible practice?

**Gerrits answer:**

As you can see, it is completely blank. Because only users that are logged in can see it through the version history, I have decided to include the actual text of it here:

> <!-- You can use *proper* HTML tags to effect the same, rather than
>   stuff that gets stripped and that will display a warning next to the
>   edit box. -->
>
> <!-- I think it should be fine.  I can't think of any reason why it
>   would be harmful. -->

Answer (score 4, accepted):

